# How to convert a URI containing partial relative path like '/../' in the middle?

Tags: python, uri, relative-path

LibreOffice API object is returning a URI path that contains relative path in the middle of the string, like:

`file:///C:/Program%20Files/LibreOffice/program/../share/gallery/sounds/apert2.wav`

How to convert this to the absolute like:

`file:///C:/Program%20Files/LibreOffice/share/gallery/sounds/apert2.wav`

How would I convert this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so Window convert forward slashes to back slash in this context.

Here is my final solution.

```py
def uri_absolute(uri: str) -> str:
    uri_re = r"^(file:(?:/*))"
    # converts
    # file:///C:/Program%20Files/LibreOffice/program/../share/gallery/sounds/apert2.wav
    # to
    # file:///C:/Program%20Files/LibreOffice/share/gallery/sounds/apert2.wav
    result = os.path.normpath(uri)
    # window will use back slash so convert to forward slash
    result = result.replace("\\", "/")
    # result may now start with file:/ and not file:///

    # add proper file:/// again
    result = re.sub(uri_re, "file:///", result, 1)
    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `os.path.normpath`:

```
import os

os.path.normpath("file:///C:/Program%20Files/LibreOffice/program/../share/gallery/sounds/apert2.wav")
```

Output:

```
'file:/C:/Program%20Files/LibreOffice/share/gallery/sounds/apert2.wav'
```

Note that the prefix is not correct anymore. So you may have to remove the `"file:///"` part first, then use `normpath`, then prepend the `"file:///"` part again.

Comment: Looks like this will work just fine. Thank you.